# JFrame image display at frame resize

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have this JFrame containing a children of JPanel wherein it displays the image which is declared in this manner.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(filename);
```

The program displays the image properly. But the only thing is, it requires to resize the frame to display the image.

Is there a possible way to display the image once the frame appears?

Comment: May be this happens because you are adding image after showing the frame. As solution you should first add image then make frame visible or you can also call repaint() after adding image.

Comment: @Cyril Horad, if would help if you provided more sample code.

Comment: Can you make the comment an answer for clear the thread. Thanks. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Perhaps, you could try implementing the paint method again in your own class that extends JPanel like this: http://pastebin.com/3ZwVvr2v and making sure that super.paintComponent(g) is called upon creation of your JPanel so that the JFrame is drawn with the image.

Comment: Could you also post the code where you drawing image?

Comment: @little, it may seemed odd. But I've tried making a method returning BufferedImage from the same code line above. And on the paint(Graphics g) method, I used that method and it worked.

Comment: @Cyril Horad, you should never explicitly invoke `paint(...)` or override it.

Comment: @Cyril Horad paint(...) is delegated for Awt and BasicXxxUI, for painting in the Swing is there paintComponent(...) as sugested @Kevin Gurney and @little bunny foo foo too

Comment: @Cyril Horad, please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) and draw the image therein. In this case, you should do this for the `JPanel` component (I think? If not, do this for the `JComponent`(s) you're referring to). Also, since Swing is not thread-safe, ensure these modifications are performed in the `EDT`.

**EXAMPLE**

```
public class Demo{
    private static BufferedImage bi;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            loadImage();
            
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            // handle exception
        }
    }
    
    private static void loadImage() throws IOException{
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resource/braveheart.PNG"));
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                Graphics g2 = g.create();
                g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
                g2.dispose();
            }
            
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
            }
        };
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

It's important to keep in mind that this example ignores rendering hints, so when you maximize the `JFrame`, the image quality will be very poor. :)

**EDIT**

When answering this question, I assumed you had a basic understanding of Swing. I suppose I assumed too much. It is important to mention that all components should be added to the top-level container before it's been *realized* (i.e. made visible). This will ensure that everything is rendered without having to resize your frame. As others have suggested, you could have simply used a `JLabel` to render the image, and then added it to your `JPanel`. Instead, I promoted custom painting, which is perfectly acceptable, and to me, cleaner.

Comment: What's the differences between paint(Graphics g) with paintComponent(Graphics g)?

Comment: @Cyril Horad, `paint(...)` handles painting the content, borders, and children of any Swing component, whereas `paintComponent(...)` is used for rendering the Swing component, and is overridden when custom rendering is desired.

Comment: @little bunny foo foo for little bit complicated way +1

Comment: @camickr, I'm not sure how overriding `paintComponent(...)` is "reinventing the wheel"? It's definitely lower-level than using a `JLabel`, but it's certainly not reinventing the wheel. To me, by using a `JLabel`, all you're doing is delegating the image rendering to another component.

Comment: Why are you promoting custom painting over using a JLabel? I always thought one of the goals of programming was to NOT reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Any time you extend a class it is custom code. Adding custom code when the functionality is supported directly is "reinventing the wheel" to me. Also this question is not about how to do painting it is about how to show the image when the frame is displayed. No where in your answer do you mention the real problem is the usage of setVisible(). Now the poster thinks the solution is the paintComponent() method, not about invoking setVisible after components have been added to the frame

Comment: @camickr, I guess I assumed that OP had a basic understanding of Swing. There's nothing wrong with the approach I promoted, in fact I think it's more preferable, but that's just a matter of opinion. I'm sorry our views on this do not align.

Comment: @camickr, are you done? if you find my answer insufficient, feel free to chime in and provide an answer of your own. there's absolutely nothing wrong with my answer. although I didn't explicitly address certain problems, I implicitly answered them.

Comment: When displaying text do you use a JLabel, or do you create a custom component and use the Graphics.drawString() method? I'm guessing you use a JLabel, so why do you favour custom painting of an image instead of letting a JLabel do all the work for you? I'm not trying to be a pain in the butt here. I honestly don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

for dispaly [Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) or [ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) is better look for [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) (basic stuff)

Comment: +1, I agree, use existing components instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @camickr, funny how you up-vote this (because this answer aligns with your opinion), although @mKorbel neglected to address the original problem. this is why I take your criticism with a grain of salt. :)

Comment: @little bunny foo foo, it's not funny at all. That is the point of upvoting an answer. You vote for what you think is the best approach. I believe using a JLabel to display an image is better than using custom code. Whether this solves the problem or not, it is still a true statement. Whenever I make a comment I gave a reason for a comment so people can can make an informed decision. Stating something is "more preferable" without giving any reasons means nothing :)

Comment: @camickr, hahahaha I find it to be hilarious.

Comment: @camickr @little bunny foo foo, please last turn off light, Rob ++

Comment: @mKorbel, lmao...whatever dude. you're both ridiculous.